# Login from @Route("/login", name="login") works great but not from the homepage

Tags: symfony, authentication

Since I've managed to setup a login form that works great when you access the Route "/login", I tried to include the form inside another twig template in order to login from the homepage and not only from a dedicated page/Route for UX purpose.

But that's not as easy as just include the form huh ?

login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include "components/login.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

login.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputUser" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{ last_username }}" name="_username" id="inputUser" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="_password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
        Sign in
    </button>
</form>
```

security.yaml

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            provider: from_database
            form_login:
                check_path: login
                login_path: login
                default_target_path: admin
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: home
```

SecurityController.php

```
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
```

Tried to add AuthenticationUtils to the homepage

```
    /**
    * @Route("/", name="home")
    */
    public function home(ArticleRepository $repo, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {
        $articles = $repo->sortDesc();
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('home/home.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
            'articles' => $articles,
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
            ]);
    }
```

As the `login.html` is just include in another template and that the home Route "/" doesn't match the "/login" Route, my Controllers have no idea what to do ?

If someone have some hints, that would be breathtaking. Thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your login form is submitted to the `/login` path:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('login') }}">
```

Comment: Yeaaaaaah so basic html action that I forgot like the newbie I am.

Yep it's easy as just include the form...

Thank you !